# How to prevent Number.parseFloat from automatically rounding the number?

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(Number.parseFloat('123456789021.123457'));
```

Output: 123456789021.12346

Expected output: 123456789021.123457

Why does the Number.parseFloat function automatically round the last digit?

Comment: what output are you expecting from that number string?

Comment: Short answer: Because it has too many digits. Long answer see: linked duplicate

Comment: Specifically look at T.J. Crowder's answer on the linked dup.

Comment: What about [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) ?